# document.getElementById for iFrame in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my site, I need to send information (via postMessage) to an iFrame. I know in regular Javascript, I would accomplish this by using `document.getElementById` or `$("#iframe")` in JQuery to select the iframe. However, I am unsure of how to do this in ReactJS. Is there a specific way of doing this in ReactJS/NextJS that I just don't know about? I need access to the iframe (the child component) from its container (parent component).

Comment: Is the `iframe` rendered via React, or in some other way?

Comment: rendered via ReactJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `iframe` is rendered by React, and only the component that renders it (or its descendants) needs to access it, then typically you use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs).

If the `iframe` is always on the page, or rendered in some way outside of React, it's perfectly fine to get it via `document.getElementById`, `document.querySelector`, or other DOM methods.

---

Here's an example of using a ref in a functional component via [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), but you can do the same thing (in a different way) in a class component via [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref). I'll use a `div` instead of an `iframe`, but it's the same for `iframe`s.

```js
function Example() {
    const ref = React.useRef(null);
    
    const doSomething = () => {
        if (ref.current) {
            console.log(`The div's text is "${ref.current.textContent}"`);
        } else {
            console.log("The div doesn't exist");
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={ref}>
            This is the target div
            </div>
            <input type="button" onClick={doSomething} value="Click Me" />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Class component example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = React.createRef();
        this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }
    
    doSomething() {
        if (this.ref.current) {
            console.log(`The div's text is "${this.ref.current.textContent}"`);
        } else {
            console.log("The div doesn't exist");
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div ref={this.ref}>
                This is the target div
                </div>
                <input type="button" onClick={this.doSomething} value="Click Me" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do I need to use componentDidMount for document.getElementById? FYI: iframe component is rendered by React.

Comment: If I use ref, is that necessary?

Comment: @CodeRocks - Unless it's completely outside the tree of the component rendering it, then I wouldn't use `getElementById` at all; I'd use a ref. If it's completely outside the tree of the component and you're definitely going to use `getElementById`, then yes, doing it in `componentDidMount` would make sense, that's where [you usually set up subscriptions](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) in class components.

Comment: @CodeRocks - If you use a ref, you don't use `getElementById` at all; you use `ref.current` instead. Since you're using class components, I'm adding a class component example now.

Comment: @CodeRocks - I've added it now. Happy coding! :-)

Comment: Thank you. One more thing -- I need to access the iframe from the iframe's parent component. How would I do this using ref if that's best practice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216297/discussion-between-coderocks-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @CodeRocks - We're getting into the long grass a bit. I suggest posting a new question showing your structure with a runnable example ([here's how](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)) and asking how you'd access the `iframe` from wherever it is you want to do that.